# OpenAL Stream not updating

Tags: c#, opentk, openal

I am currently having some issues with OpenAL. I start to stream a sound and then call a function which will try to queue what remains of the sound if it is not loaded on the initial play call. At the moment when a large sound is initially played it doesn't update the data on the source.

Here is the source used to try and fill the channels buffer:

```
private void EnsureBufferFilled(Int32 sourceId, List<Int32> bufferIds)
    {
        if(!_Registered || bufferIds.Count == 0) return;

        Task t = new Task(() =>
        {
            List<Int32> loadedIds = new List<Int32>();

            foreach (Int32 bufferId in bufferIds)
            {
                if (AL.IsBuffer(bufferId))
                {
                    AL.SourceQueueBuffer(sourceId, bufferId);
                    loadedIds.Add(bufferId);
                }
                else break;
            }

            bufferIds.RemoveRange(0, loadedIds.Count);

            if (bufferIds.Count != 0)
            {
                EnsureBufferFilled(sourceId, bufferIds);
            }
        });
        t.Start();
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: After you load and queue the buffers don't you have to call AL.SourcePlay?

Comment: The call to AL.SourcePlay is outside of this function, this function is trying to queue data to a playing channel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue with this was in the below logic:

```
if (AL.IsBuffer(bufferId))
```

This was simply checking to see if the buffer was created and not if all the data had been loaded. This meant that when the checks were being performed I was trying to queue buffers without data.

In order to fix this I added an additional check to see if the data relating to the buffer was loaded (a function I wrote into my own custom audio data class).